# Camel FTP Issue Related To Large File Transfer

Tags: apache-camel

I am working on a requirement related to downloading large size files through camel-ftp component.
Route definition is as below :

```
from("sftp://host:22?connectTimeout=30000&username=xxx&password=yyyy&localWorkDirectory=D:/templocation")
.to("file:///D:/mylocation");
```

I am looking for an answer to the below questions.

1. Does Camel SFPT supports resume functionality in case there is a server disconnect.I have observed that .inprogress file
   gets deleted once SocketTimeout/IOException exception is thrown from underlying JSCH library. My expectation is that camel should re establish 
   the connection once it is available and resume downloading from the point where it left.
2. Parameters such as connectTimeout, timeout and soTimeout have no effect. In windows platform(WIN 7), if the server stays disconnected for
   approximately 21 seconds, Camel deletes the .inprogress file. Is there any other parameter in camel FTP component that has to be set
   to control consumer timeout. Issue would be if the file size is very large(1 GB or more) and server gets disconnected when more that
   90% is downloaded.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For number 1 then answer is no

Answer (score 0):

@ClausIbsen :
Thank you so much for your answer. I would really appreciate your feedback on point 2.

I went through Camel FTP component source code and found SftpOperations.retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory
is the method where the functionality related to retrieving data from JSch library is implemented.

Code is such that any exception received from underlying library will cause the .inprogress file to get deleted
i,e channel.get(remoteName, os);. I investigated JSch library where they have a option of resume :

```
get(String src, OutputStream dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode, long skip) 
Downloads a file to an OutputStream.
```

I incorporated this API in retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory method by tracking if there is any .inprogress file
and if exists, it's filesize.

```
if(fileSize>0)
{
  channel.get(remoteName, os, progressMonitor, ChannelSftp.RESUME, fileSize    );
}
else
{
 channel.get(remoteName, os, progressMonitor);
}
```

ProgressMonitor implementation helps me to track if the download is complete or not.

```
fileSize=temp.length();
boolean isFileDownloadComplete=(fileSize==progressMonitor.getMax());
if(isFileDownloadComplete)
    rename and move the file.
```

With the above implementation and commenting out the original file deletion behaviour, download resume functionality is working.
I am able to resume file download even though server disconnect .

I have one question here : 
Do you foresee any implementation flaw here in the above solution.
Is there any functionality that is going to be impacted which I missed.
I would really appreciate your feedback.